# Mongo error when loading on mobile

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mobile, mongoose

I am getting the following error on mongo, when loading my test MEAN app on my mobile phone.

I have no idea which module is that, since I am not loading it myself.

The wierd part is that, on desktop browser, the error does not pop up.

I am using mongoose as mongodb driver. Probably the error has something to do with it.

Any insights?

```
Error: Cannot find module '../schemas/favicon.icSchema'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at modelNamer (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/routes/general.js:13:10)
    at /home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/routes/general.js:19:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at param (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:349:14)
    at param (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
```

Comment: Can you share the code around: `/home/rafapaulin/lab/rpg-am/routes/general.js:13:10`.  It might help.

Comment: sure @unflores 

    `var modelNamer = function(collection){ 
        return require('../schemas/' + collection.slice(0, -1) + 'Schema') 
    };`

basically, this function builds the name of the model, based on the route passed.

it is working on desktop, and actually, it works on POST requests on mobile too... that error just pop when the page is loaded on mobile, but the routes still works

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think that there is maybe some magic happening with your path here.  You could try logging what the current path is when calling this from both your desktop and mobile.

Or you could try something like the following: [absolute requires](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#7-the-wrapper) which will ensure that you are requireing something with an absolute path from your server.js directory.